# Looking for a particular happiness dataset

Tags: dataset

Im looking for a particular dataset I found before but did not download and now I can't seem to find it again (many google searches and checked my history).

I believe it contains around somewhere from 10-40K sentences from people who basically describe a pleasant event during the day and how it made them feel. They're all happy emotions like cheerful, tranquil etc... I believe it's a pretty famous dataset. Would love to run some deep learning practice with it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the dataset in the question on kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/ritresearch/happydb?select=cleaned_hm.csv